# Meteor SSR how to load images on localhost?

Tags: meteor

I'm generating a pdf on server-side using Meteor SSR and node html-pdf library.

My problem is I can't load images from localhost. I'm trying to get the path to the image using Meteor.absoluteUrl, like below:

```
var imageUrl = Meteor.absoluteUrl( 'images/logo1.png' );
```

which resolves to http://localhost:3000/images/logo1.png, when I access this url directly on the browser it return the image. But it doesn't load rendering the html with SSR.

If I image source for an external image it resolves.

Is it possible to render images from localhost using Meteor SSR?

Thank you.

**Edit**

It is working on the pdf, but it doesn't work if I send the html response to the browser like this:

```
response.writeHead( 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'} );
response.end( html );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your image in the `public` folder. The url you are aiming for is pointing to your `public/images/logo1.png` app folder.

if you need your image to be private, I advise you to choose, depending on your image size, a blob storing in the mongoDB or a gridFS storage (if your images can be bigger than 16mb), using collectionFS or file-collection packages.